# Asp.Net - Redirect if JavaScript is not enabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net-3.5

I got this code in my Master page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%=hfJavaScriptDetected.ClientID %>").val('yes');
 </script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hfJavaScriptDetected" runat="server" Value="no" />
```

So if JavaScript is enabled the value of my hidden field should have be changed.

Now, what I would like to do is check this value on server side and if it's set to "no", I want to redirect the user to the page Javascript.Aspx.

I don't know in which event to look the hidden field value. I try on the Page_Load event but it's seems the hidden field value was not already set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

would this not be easier like this?

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=http://www.mysite.com/Javascript.Aspx"/> 
</noscript>
```

If the browser has javascript enabled, the inner content is ignored... but if they don't the meta tag says, in **1** second, **refresh** this page... and the new URL is ...**Javascript.Aspx**

Comment: I liked this approach. The user need not have to submit the page to detect js is disabled or not.

Comment: Is there a negative side to use this method. It's always work ? Because yesterday I googled a lot to find a solution and I always end up with complicated script so I wonder why nobody have suggest this method ?

Comment: @Melursus - I can't really think of one.  I think most of the snippets out there are the reverse... see if JavaScript is available, then redirect.  I presume in your case that JS is required for the site, thus you just want to redirect a user if they have turned it off.  The meta tag should work fine for this. You can of course change the timer to 0 if you want instant... or longer if needed.  The only catch I know, is that once a meta refresh tag has been read, you can't unset it in the browser. If you remove the tag (via JS), the browser won't unhook the request to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not set is because `$("#<%=hfJavaScriptDetected.ClientID %>")` is null. You need to wait for the page to load before you can set values.

What you want is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#<%=hfJavaScriptDetected.ClientID %>").val('yes');
});
```

Comment: I try it but when I'm in the Page_Load event the value is still set to 'no'

Comment: try doing

$("#<%=hfJavaScriptDetected.ClientID %>").attr("value", "yes");

Comment: I try and it's doesn't work. But I know the value is being change to 'yes' because if I do an alert, it's show 'yes'. I think the problem is when I try to see the value in the Page_Load event, this event have not already occurs ? So maybe I need to check in in another event ?

Comment: oh yea, data population occurs after the page_load event. you could either use the onvaluechanged event of the hidden field, load complete, or look at the request.forms item collection. : )

Comment: I try your 3 solutions without success... I'm pretty new at playing with Javascript along with the server-side. My feeling is that because the value is change by client-side, the server-side doesn't have access to this new value ? I would really appreciate if you can try at your own the solutions you proposed and tell me if you are able to make one work. Thx!